# <activeProfile> in maven settings xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

there is a global settings xml file provided that contains 3 profiles and a active profile

```
<profiles>
 <profile>P1</profile>
 <profile>P2</profile>
 <profile>P3</profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
 <activeProfile>P1</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

When i run the maven build i want to choose any one of the 3 profiles .

PS : i cannot use the mvn cli to activate profiles due to restriction in my build environment but have full control to add a user settings xml or modify the above global settings xml if needed.

If i add a new user settings xml with only the below

```
<activeProfiles>
 <activeProfile>P2</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

my expectation was the the user settings `activeProfile` (P2) to take preference but i still see the global settings `activeProfile` (P1) active.

how can i achieve this without using the mvn cli and if possibly dont modifying the global settings xml?

Comment: My first question would be: Why do you have so many profiles in your settings?

Comment: the profiles are needed for different build qualities each requiring a different plugin repositories

Comment: What is a build quality? The build should always the same... ? Nor different repositories?

Comment: For eg : Build quality of type release uses a different pvt repository

Comment: Build quality sounds like you don't understand maven very well. In general there are two things a SNAPSHOT state (indicated by using a version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`) which is by default deployed into snapshot repository and a release (indicated by a version like `1.0.0`) which is deploy by default into release repository. So there no need for a profile...

Comment: yes I am a newbie to the maven world, apologies i may not have explained it clearer, in my organization, the maven build must happen in a isolated environment and downloading of dependencies cannot happen from the maven central and there are internal nexus repo from where the dependencies get resolved from. Profile contains the repository url and id. Snapshot build must use the snapshot repository for dependency  resolution , release build must be the release repo and there are other such build type . Hope that explains a little better

Comment: In particular if you have internal repo manager you should move the configuration to the settings.xml where it belongs (also for CI environment) your repo manager should be configured accordingly. Using snapshot dependencies will be resolved by a repository manager based on the configuration with SNAPSHOT dependencies and release are resolved based on their version (1.0.9 -> release) and there is no need for profiles for such separation and it does not make sense.. furthermore it sounds like there is a lot of misunderstanding how Maven works and a repository manager works...

Comment: maybe :) was not the one involved in how the those settings.xml were created and how the are enforced, wanted to understand irrespective of the incorrect usage if the <activeProfile> present in one settings.xml can be  overridden ? (without the mvn cli)